# Terminal on brand new macbook 2023 with Mac OSX Ventura 13.2 gives error "zsh: command not found: python"

Tags: python, macos-ventura

Terminal on brand new macbook 2023 with M2 chip and Mac OSX Ventura 13.2 gives error "zsh: command not found: python".

Haven't been able to find answer on google.

Comment: You need to install Python, go to the official python website and you will surely find information on how to install

Comment: ok. thanks for the information. I guess I was just really surprised that python doesn't come installed. My old macbook from 2013 had it preinstalled.